# File indentation changes for different text editors

Tags: python, vim, editor, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I like to code in both vim and sublime, sometimes using both interchangably on the same file. Recently I tried running a python script and it gave me an indentation error. Turns out that the same file was indented differently in vim and sublime.

My question is: Is there a way to avoid this? Or is there no guarantee that the formatting of my files will stay the same if I use different text editors?

**File opened in sublime:**

[image: Sublime]

**File opened in vim:**

[image: vim]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a mixture of spaces and tabs for indentation. This can be very confusing to a human reader as the indentation could appear different depending on how the code is viewed. Fortunately, the Python interpreter is nice enough to spot this and tell you.

One good strategy is to always use spaces as this will give you consistent formatting and indentation across editors/IDEs irrespective of their settings.

To change all tabs to spaces in vim:

```
:set tabstop=4
:set expandtab
:%retab
```

(You might want to add the first two commands to your `.vimrc`, at least for Python files.)

Comment: You also need to consider that the `ftplugin/python.vim` may override the global settings for `'tabstop'` and `'expandtab'`, and to consistently determine the indent, don't forget `'softtabstop'` and `'shiftwidth'`, too.

Comment: I agree with Ingo. Please do *not* put bare indention setting in your `~/.vimrc` file. Put the commands either in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` or `~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim`. If you rather all your setting in your vimrc file then do something like this: `autocmd FileType python set tabstop=4 expandtab`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org/) and the different plugins to keep the same indentation across IDEs and projects.

It's very easy to use and setup and you just need to install the plugins.

Saved me a lot of overhead! :)